# Помогите с парсером на питоне

Tags: python

есть парсер на питоне(полный код скидывать не буду), нужно достать описание товара из картрочки, но не знаю как это сделать

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import lxml
url = 'https://www.specodegda.ru/product/kostyum-professional-2-genesis-genezis-seryy-hakitbejevyygorchichnyy/'
request = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(request.text, 'lxml')
discription = soup.find('div', class_ = 'product-info')
discriptions = discription.find_all('p')
for discription in discriptions:
    print(discription.text)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `product-info__content` или `product-description`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import lxml
url = 'https://www.specodegda.ru/product/kostyum-professional-2-genesis-genezis-seryy-hakitbejevyygorchichnyy/'
request = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(request.text, 'lxml')
discription = soup.find('div', class_="product-info__content product-description")
print(discription.text)

Костюм состоит из куртки и полукомбинезона.
Куртка прямого силуэта на поясе, с центральной застежкой на молнию YKK. Отложной воротник с лацканами. Множество функциональных карманов. Имеются складки на спинке для обеспечения свободы движения. Рукава втачные с манжетой по низу и усилением в области локтя. Прилегание пояса куртки регулируется хлястиками. В подмышечной области вентиляционные детали из сетки.
Полукомбинезон с центральной застежкой на молнию YKK и с нагрудными карманами. Застежки фастекс закрыты муфтой из ткани, двойная резинка в бретелях. Шаговый шов усилен двойной строчкой. Внутренний карман для вкладных наколенников имеет два положения по высоте. Анатомический подрез в области колена. На полукомбинезоне расположены навесные трехслойные карманы (верхний слой из трех отделений). Навесные карманы можно поместить в находящиеся под ними накладные карманы с отлетным низом. Спинка отрезная с эластичной лентой по линии талии для лучшего прилегания. На задней части полукомбинезона расположены карманы: два накладных, карман и петля для инструментов.
Дополнительную прочность соединений костюма обеспечивают двойные отделочные строчки и спец.закрепки.
```